# For which subspace a continuous function satisfying given conditions will exist?

Tags: general-topology

For which subspace $X \subseteq \mathrm{R}$ with usual topology and with $\{0,1\}\subseteq X$, will a continuous function $ f: X \to \{0,1\}$ satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ exist?

1. $X= [0,1]$
2. $X= [-1,1]$
3. $X= \mathrm{R}$
4. $[0,1] \not \subset X$

Comment: Tip: Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ a continuous function, then $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Since  for the first three options the domains are connected but the range is not connected the only possible case is the fourth option which $[0,1] \not \subset X$